# intellij tomcat server giving 404 even after following setup instructions

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I am trying to setup tomcat server on intellij to use JSP but it is keep on giving me 404 error. I have tried all the solutions that were viable on google and stack overflow; however, it has been no use.

My tomcat server is 9.0.0 and when I run localhost:8080 on my browser, it opens up the default tomcat page.

Below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
<display-name>Hello World Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jc.servlet.Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/greeting</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

below are my index.jsp which I did not even touch

```
<%--
Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
User: JC
Date: 28/09/2016
Time: 1:23 AM
To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>$Title$</title>
</head>
<body>
$END$
</body>
</html>
```

below are my servlet named Servlet under com.jc.servlet 
    package com.jc.servlet;

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by JC on 28/09/2016.
 */
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.getWriter().println("Hello World!");

}
}
```

The settings that I have executed to link tomcat server and intelliJ is to add tomcat 9.0.0 on Application Servers under settings, to deploy the exploded artifact and set application context as /hello-world

So when I go http://localhost:8080/hello-world/greeting, I should be able to see my servlet but it is giving me a 404 error. However, when I go to http://localhost:8080/ the default page loads so tomcat server is working.

Please help. I can't do anything because the server won't work

Comment: after you deployed your application to `<Tomcat-Home>/webapps/hello-world` , what is the content of the directory  `<Tomcat-Home>/webapps` ? Did you start Tomcat via IntelliJ or outside the IDE?

Comment: I am having the same issue here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77771978/ive-got-a-problem-with-servlet-deployment-issue

Answer (score 0):

web.xml: You don't close the web-app tag at the end of your servlet definition.